# FileNotFoundException when trying to create a File in Android

Tags: android, file-io, filenotfoundexception

I'm trying to use Jexcel API to create an excel file and write to it using my application on my phone. When I run the app, it throws a `FileNotFoundException`. I even tried creating a text file according to an answer to another such question, but it throws the same error. I have given the appropriate permissions in the manifest, but I still cant seem to pinpoint the problem.
Please help.

Here is my code

```
 public WritableWorkbook createWorkbook(String fileName){

    //Saving file in external storage
        File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
        File directory = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/bills");

        //create directory if not exist
        if(!directory.isDirectory()){
            directory.mkdirs();
        }

        //file path
        file= new File(directory, fileName);
        if (file.exists())
            Log.e(taf,"file created");
        else
        Log.e(taf,"file not created");

        WorkbookSettings wbSettings = new WorkbookSettings();
        wbSettings.setLocale(new Locale("en", "EN"));
        wbSettings.setUseTemporaryFileDuringWrite(true);
        WritableWorkbook workbook;
        workbook=null;

        try {
            workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(file, wbSettings);
            Log.i(taf,"workbook created");
            //Excel sheet name. 0 represents first sheet
            WritableSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("MyShoppingList", 0);

            try {
                sheet.addCell(new Label(0, 0, "Subject")); // column and row
                sheet.addCell(new Label(1, 0, "Description"));


                        String title = "blaj";
                        String desc = "nxjdncj";

                        int i = 1;
                        sheet.addCell(new Label(0, i, title));
                        sheet.addCell(new Label(1, i, desc));
            } catch (WriteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            workbook.write();
            try {
                workbook.close();
            } catch (WriteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return workbook;
}
```

On executing, the log message " file not created " is printed. Im new to android so please point out even the most basic issues.

Thank you.

Comment: your Android version is 6.0 ?

Comment: yes. It works for pre marshmallow devices. I have read that for marshmallow devices you have to add run time permissions but I dont exactly know how to add those.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instantiating `File` does not create the file, just gives you a `File` instance whether a file with that particular path and file name exists or not.

Check out the source code of the constructor:

```
public File(String dirPath, String name) {
    if (name == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("name == null");
    }
    if (dirPath == null || dirPath.isEmpty()) {
        this.path = fixSlashes(name);
    } else if (name.isEmpty()) {
        this.path = fixSlashes(dirPath);
    } else {
        this.path = fixSlashes(join(dirPath, name));
    }
}
```

To actually create the file you could do something like this:

```
if (!file.exists()) {
    // file does not exist, create it
    file.createNewFile();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add one more line under:

```
file= new File(directory, fileName);
file.createNewFile();// add this line
```

I hope already you have added permissions in manifest file.